# What is a server address?

Tags: terminology

I'm still new to Minecraft and I tried to make a multiplayer server to play with my friend, but there is something I don't understand, Server Address? Can someone explain what that is?

Comment: Do you mean server-ip in the server.properties file?

Comment: I think making a server in multiplayer, I'm really new so I don't exactly understand

Comment: Please include some context for "Server Address"

Comment: Server-ip, yea, I mean server-ip

Comment: You should edit the question to reflect that.  I would recommend giving it a more informative title such as "What does server-ip mean in server.properties?"

Answer (score 8):

You might want to take a look at Minecraft Wiki's [article on server setup](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server#Server_Setup). They also have a very useful tutorial on [setting up a server](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server) as well.

If you're wondering about something more specific, take a look at the article on the [server.properties file](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties), which explains how you can customize your server to fit your needs.

As for what exactly `server-ip` does, it's unnecessary. You might as well leave it blank.

Comment: It's for multiple nic cards on a machine. Blank auto detects

Comment: @Resorath – I understand that, but for nearly all situations it only adds confusion. I doubt it's necessary here.

Comment: It is for running multiple minecraft servers on a single system.

Comment: @Zoredache Isn't that sort of what port is for? I don't think changing the IP will help all that much in most situations.